# Passing parameters to form with link_to for has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am Rails newbie and having some trouble passing parameters to form.

I have a Course model and Lesson model. Courses and Lessons are connected with a have_many :through association. Code is below:

```
    class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :description, :name

      has_many :course_listings
      has_many :lessons, through: :course_listings

    end

    class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :title, :body, :category_ids

      has_many :course_listings
      has_many :courses, through: :course_listings

    end

    class CourseListing < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :course_id, :lesson_id

      belongs_to :course
      belongs_to :lesson
    end
```

I want to allow users to add lessons to an existing, i.e., create a new course listing. Right now I have the following on app/views/courses/show.html.erb

```
    <%= link_to 'Add New Lesson', new_course_listing_path(course_id: @course.id) %>
```

In the CourseListingsController, I have:

```
    def new
      @course_listing = CourseListing.new
      if params[:course_id]
        @course_listing.course_id = params[:course_id]
      end
    end
```

In the form for new course listing, I have:

```
    <%= form_for(@course_listing) do |f| %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :course_id, value: @course_id %>

  <%= f.label :lesson_id, "Enter Lesson" %>
  <%= f.text_field :lesson_id %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>

    <% end %>
```

The code above is not submitting the course id. In the log I see:

```
    Parameters: {..., "course_listing"=>{"course_id"=>"", "lesson_id"=>"7"},   
    "commit"=>"Save Lesson"}
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

As you can see from above, the course_id is not being passed into the CourseListingsController. Have spent quite a bit of time looking into this and any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Save your self days of headaches with simple_form - forms in rails made easy - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's potentially a few issues going on here.

- You've referenced :text_lessons above as well as Lessons. Is that a typo?
- Having a controller for CourseListings isn't the ideal way of doing it; you should be creating a nested lesson through the course model. Please see this railscast  http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. TextLesson was typo - it's fixed. I will check out the railscast for nested model and see if I can go that route

Answer (score 0):

You use the @course_id variable in the view, but I don't see where it's set? When you inspect the page, is there a value in there? Also, the nested attributes tip is a great one. You'll want to use that pattern often enough to make learning it now valuable. (and quick typo/fix "have_many" is obviously has_many. The more you make sure you never type it correctly, the less likely it'll sneak into your code).

Comment: I was attempting to set the course_id from the course show page with <%= link_to 'Add New Lesson', new_course_listing_path(course_id: @course.id) %>. But I've now learned that link_to only accepts html options so I will be going to nested attributes route.